# setting the width of a label control

Tags: c#, css, visual-studio-2008

Using the `Label` control, the display text is set during runtime from the database. I am trying to control the maximum width of the control, for example max of 100 per line with additional characters rolled over to the next line.

I tried this by setting and also using CSS with no luck:

```
lbl_Feedback1.Width = 50;
```

I believe the issue lies with the fact that the text of the label is updated during run time of the application. How to solve this?

Comment: I assume this is ASP.NET with the css tag but MVC or Webforms?

Comment: Please show the HTML output for this label. I think .NET is using a SPAN, which cannot accept a width unless it is set to display:block;

Comment: Any reason why you want to use a span instead of a div?

Comment: @kenny - yes using .net, i can attach a css style to the label or can also set it in the code. Neither helps

Comment: @Diodeus - I am writing this in C#. The html code is generated automatically.

Comment: @James Johnson - I am not using a div. I can apply any css to a .net label control.

Comment: Label = span; Panel = div. For what you're describing, a div (Panel) would be more appropriate.

Comment: User: Yes, it is the "automatically generated" code that we need to see. The problem with .NET is that it isolates you so much from the actual HTML so much that you don't even know how it works.

Comment: None of the solutions helped, so what I did in the code was to separate the string manually in C#.

Answer (score 8):

Your label must be set to "display: block" in order to set a width.
Either set this in the css-file:

```
label, span {
display: block
}
```

or using inline style (from code-behind):

```
lbl_Feedback1.Style["display"] = "block";
lbl_Feedback1.Style["width"] = "100px";
```

Comment: Hmm.. It really should work. Maybe you have a container with a fixed width.

What happens with the exess text? Does it just disappear?

Could you post the resulting HTML and/or a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried the `max-width` property?  eg: max-width:100px;

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

> display:inline-block;

It worked for me.